# Flutter Dialog Components appearing behind dialog during animation

Tags: android, flutter, dart

### Overview:

I have a dialog box which contains 7 components:

- Icon
- Title Text
- Quantity Indicator
- Quantity Field
- Link Field
- A Button (Container with Gesture Detector)
- Container (For Background)

I also have a `SquareTile()` widget which has the Icon, Title Text and the Background container wrapped with hero widgets so that it smoothly transitions between opening and closing the dialog.

### Problem:

Excluding the icon, title text and the background container, all the other widgets do not have a transition or any other widget such as `Hero()` to do any type of transition, so the other widgets first appear behind the dialog while its transitioning and when the transition is finished, they just pop in front of the dialog.

### What I'm trying to do:

I have set up an external file named `dialog_visibility.dart` which simply contains a boolean `isDialogVisible` which I set to true when the user clicks on the `SquareTile()` widget I mentioned earlier, when it is true, I want the other widgets to fade in when the dialog box is open and fade out while closing but it doesn't seem to be working as expected, please watch this video to understand what I am saying:

https://youtu.be/V9W56FC0BfE

### Code:

**Instagram.dart**

```dart
GestureDetector(
             onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isDialogVisible = true;
                });
                _showDialog(
                  context,
                  const Icon(Icons.group_rounded),
                  'Followers',
                  '3043',
                  0.25,
                );
              },
              child: const SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 200,
                child: SquareTile(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.group_rounded),
                  text: 'Followers',
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

**tile.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/page/test.dart';
import 'my_dialog.dart';

class SquareTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const SquareTile({
    required this.icon,
    required this.text,
    super.key,
  });

  final Icon icon;
  final String text;

  @override
  State<SquareTile> createState() => _SquareTileState();
}

class _SquareTileState extends State<SquareTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: 'my_hero_tag',
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 10,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                child: Hero(
                  tag: 'icon_hero_tag',
                  child: widget.icon,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 80,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 150,
                child: Center(
                  child: Hero(
                    tag: 'text_hero_tag',
                    child: Material(
                      type: MaterialType.transparency,
                      child: Text(
                        widget.text,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**my_dialog.dart**

```dart
// ignore_for_file: override_on_non_overriding_member

import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/components/service_field.dart';
import 'package:smooth_like_flutter/dialog_visibility.dart';

class AlignedDialogRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
  AlignedDialogRoute({
    super.settings,
    this.padding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,
    required this.heroTag,
    required this.iconHeroTag,
    required this.textHeroTag,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(fullscreenDialog: false);

  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final Alignment alignment;

  final String title = 'Followers';
  final double priceOfOne = 0.25;

  final quantityController = TextEditingController();
  final linkController = TextEditingController();
  var totalPrice = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  /// The tag used to match the Hero transition widgets.
  final String heroTag;
  final String textHeroTag;
  final String iconHeroTag;

  /// The builder will create the widget that we want to show in the dialog.
  final Widget Function(
    BuildContext,
    Animation<double>,
    Animation<double>,
  ) builder;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isDialogVisible = false;
              });
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Hero(
              tag: heroTag,
              child: Container(
                height: 450,
                width: 280,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1.5),
                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 350),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Hero(
                    tag: iconHeroTag,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.group_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Hero(
                    tag: textHeroTag,
                    child: Material(
                      type: MaterialType.transparency,
                      child: Text(
                        title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: totalPrice,
                        builder: (context, value, child) {
                          return Text(
                            value.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[700]),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 22,
                        height: 22,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/coin.png'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  AnimatedOpacity(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutExpo,
                    opacity: checkDialog(isDialogVisible),
                    child: MyServiceField(
                      type: TextInputType.number,
                      controller: quantityController,
                      hint: 'Quantity',
                      onChange: (fieldData) {
                        var fieldNum = int.parse(fieldData);
                        totalPrice.value = fieldNum * priceOfOne;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  MyServiceField(
                    type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    controller: linkController,
                    hint: 'Link',
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 49,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);

                      setState(() {
                        isDialogVisible = false;
                      });

                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.error_outline,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              title: const Text("Notice"),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              contentTextStyle:
                                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                              content: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  ConstrainedBox(
                                    constraints:
                                        const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
                                    child: const Text(
                                      "Your order has been placed and will be completed within 2 to 10 Hours.",
                                      style: TextStyle(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              actions: [
                                Center(
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      height: 50,
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(10))),
                                      child: const Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                        'Ok',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ))
                              ],
                            );
                          });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: ConstrainedBox(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100),
                          child: const Text(
                            'Place Order',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => Colors.black54;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => "Dialog dismissal barrier";

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 5000);
}

checkDialog(bool isDialogVisible) {
  double opacity;

  if (isDialogVisible) {
    opacity = 0.0;
  } else {
    opacity = 1.0;
  }
  return opacity;
}
```